# get glympse url without user interaction

Tags: android, glympse

I am writing an automation app and would like to share Glympse location automatically without user interaction when the user starts to drive.

I took a look at the SDK to use Android intents, and it looks like I can populate all details, but to get a link, the user still needs to click the "Create" button that pops up. I get the created link back in my app only after the user clicks the "Create" button.

Is there a way for my app to get the Glympse url without user interaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending a Glympse without an explicit user action is not currently supported through the Glympse app. It's technically possible to do it using the Glympse client SDK, but doing so goes against the stated "Best Practices for Respecting User Privacy" https://developer.glympse.com/docs/core/guidelines

> A Glympse sharing event should be initiated only by an explicit user action on the Glympse form (e.g. user needs to tap "Send" on the Glympse form to start the Glympse). In other words, your application may not programmatically invoke the "Send" command on behalf of the user.

Comment: I apologize but I am a bit confused. Isn't the client SDK sort of an intent wrapper for the android app? If so how can the app not support it but technically possible using the sdk? I am writing this for a closed group of users numbering less than 10. It would be helpful if you could expand on how its technically possible using the SDK. I am also not sure how the REST api falls into the scheme of things here.

Comment: The intent SDK is what you are using to call into the Glympse app. The Glympse client SDK is a bit different as it lets applications interact with the Glympse service without needing the Glympse app installed. It's actually the same thing that the Glympse app uses under the covers to talk to the Glympse servers.